# How to avoid paint overshooting?

Tags: texturing

[image]

I want to be able to paint the eyebrows of the mesh without paint overshooting onto it's forehead. How can I either:

- Adjust my workflow to stop such things happening or
- Adjust my brushes' settings to stop the overshooting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *Texture Paint* mode you can enable a ***Paint Mask*** (red arrow, screenshot 2). When it's enabled then you can only paint on faces that are selected in *Edit* mode.

For example, switch to *Edit* mode and select the eyebrows, eyes, nose, and inner mouth. Then switch to *Texture Paint* mode and enable the *Paint Mask*.

[image: selected faces in edit mode]

Now you can paint the eyebrows, eyes, nose, and mouth without overpainting the color of the face/head.

[image: paint mask]