# Help with painting on only one face

Tags: faces, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I've seen a few strands online of this question being answered, but none of them work.
I saw one that said "In the 3d Views Header, there's a box thing that you should apply." I can't find it.

I guess I should check, the 3d View Header is just the row of options on the top of your screen, right?

Anyways, I would love an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the *Paint Mask* toggle icon in the *3D View Header*? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/254651/107598

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to select the face you want to paint on in *Edit* mode, then in *Texture Paint* mode, enable the *Paint Mask* option, it will grey all the other faces:

[image]