# I want to make the eyes glow with a toon shader

Tags: node-editor, shaders, lighting, shader-nodes

I have a model with a toon shader and want to make the eyes glow like in the image/video below. But in Blender the eyes don't glow as you can see in the screenshot below.
What should I do?
I wish I could set the intensity like this.

[image: anime character with glowing eyes]

① I want to make my eyes glow
Case (Unity)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_M9YyH1h30

It seems easy with Unity, but I can't write it out well
I hope Blender can fix it.
However, I didn't know how to connect shaders and nodes.
I wonder if I should set the material for N00_000_00_EyeIris_00_EYE (Instance).

My model and shader image.
[image]
[image]

When I asked a question on Bing, it came out as follows.
I still had to fix it, but it didn't come out the same way. It's wrong, but I'll put it in the reference below for reference.

> To make your eyes glow, you need to follow these steps:
>
> - Prepare *MainTexture* and *Emission_Texture*. The *MainTexture* can be a normal eye texture. The *Emission_Texture* makes the texture
>   white only where the eye shines.
> - Connect a *Mix* node to *MainTexture* and *Emission_Texture* respectively. A *Mix* node is a node that mixes two colors. You can
>   choose between the *MainTexture* or *Emission Texture* and a color for
>   the input of the *Mix* node. For the color, use either *color1* or
>   *color2*. It doesn't matter which one you connect to, but either *color1* or *color2* must be black to be editable. The *Mix* node ignores black colors when mixing two colors. So you can't edit the
>   color of the blackened one. Don't make the color you want to edit
>   black.
> - Connect the output of the Mix node to *Mtoon_universed*. *Mtoon_universed* is a node that sets the eye material. In addition to *MainTexture* and *Emission_texture*, there are various items in the input of *Mtoon_universed*, but only *EmissionColor* and
>   *EmissionIntensity* are used this time. *EmissionColor* is an item that determines the color that the eyes glow. *EmissionIntensity* is
>   an item that determines the intensity of the eyes shining.
>   *Emissioncolor* is connected to the output of a Mix node that mixes *MainTexture* and *Emission_Texture*. Enter a number for EmissionIntensity. The higher the number, the brighter the eyes.
> - Connect the output of *Mtoon_universed* to the Main node. The Main node is the node that outputs the final material.
> - Here's how to make it stand out. The texture may not have changed in the Unity video, but I think that's because the creator of the video
>   already prepared a whitened texture. If you also have a whitened
>   texture, you don't need to change the texture.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what your *MToon_unversion* node group exactly does but to me *Emission_Texture* looks like a mask. What does your model look like when you connect the yellow output of the *Emission_Texture* node to the *Material Output*'s *Surface* input slot? I would expect that the eyes get white (=glow) and the rest will be black. -- What color is *EmissionColor*? Expand the node to check it. It must not be black.

Comment: And yes, is the material in screenshot 2 actually the material of the iris? -- Last but not least it's not clear what value the glow intensity/emission strength has. I can't find an input slot that seems to define this.

Comment: Thank you so much.
I uploaded blender file.

Comment: Thanks for the blend file. I'm going to check it. I think your first sentence (*"I would like to keep an eye on this model."*) is a translation error because "to keep an eye on someone" means "to watch them/to keep them under careful observation" ;-)

Comment: Understand.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get the eyes to glow like in your reference picture, you need to do at least 2 things, maybe even 3:

1. enable emission for the eyes in the shader to make them glow
2. tone down the skin color to simulate a dark environment. Of course, you need to do this also for the hair, clothes, and so on.
3. optionally, increase the emission strength and activate the *Bloom* option in the Eevee render setting if you want to make the eyes glow like a spotlight.

[image: examples of an anime head with glowing eyes]

The first thing to mention is that your toon shader, like most toon shaders, uses *Emission Shader* nodes to get the cartoon/anime style. This means, the head is a light source and emits light. For this reason

- it is not or hardly(*) influenced by light. Even if you set the world color to pitch black and remove all lights, you will see the head in the same color as in a bright world/environment.
- it does not get any shadows cast by other objects
- additional emission light can be added in the toon shader node group

Keep this in mind for point 2.

(*) Note: actually, depending on the toon shader's settings it will be affected a little bit by light.

### 1. Enable Emission for the Eyes

If you check out the material for the eyes *"N00_000_00_EyeIris_00_EYE (Instance)"* and expand the *Emission_Texture* and the *EmissionColor* nodes then you will see that the image *Shader_NoneBlack* is actually pure black and the color is also black. This means that there is no (additional) emission for the eyes.

[image: toon shader default settings]

To fix this,

1. set the *EmissionColor* to a non-black color. Try yellow
2. change the image texture. You can unplug the *Image Texture* node (*Emission_Texture*) and  choose just the white color. But then the pupil is also affected by the glow and becomes grey. It's better to create an image as an emission mask and paint it to control where the emission should occur.

Let's create an **emission mask**. Remove the *Shader_NoneBlack* image with the [X] button in the node, and create a new image with the [+ New] button. Create a small image (512px x 512px should be fine, no *Alpha* channel needed).

[image: new image texture for eyes]

Now you can paint the model in the *Texture Paint* workspace. Note that the eyes have their own material but share the UV map of the head parts. The UV map has overlapping UV islands from all the head parts. This results in the head being painted when you paint the eyes and vice versa. This is not technically a problem, but if you accidentally paint the eyelids or the head, it can mess up the pupils that you just carefully painted. [Use the *painting mask* option to avoid over-painting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/254637/107598). **Don't forget to save the image.**

[image: painting the mask]

### 2. Darken the Skin Tone

This can be done with the settings of the toon shader node group. Select the face material (*"N00_000_00_Face_00_SKIN (Instance)"*) and choose a grey color for the *Diffuse Color* and *ShadeColor*, and/or try the *ShadeTooy* setting.

[image: toon shader settings]

### 3. Emission Strength and Bloom

The *Bloom* is just a checkbox the *Eevee* render settings. But to see the effect, you need to increase the emission strength, which is 1 by default. It's in the shader node group. I recommend creating a new input group, then you can control the strength from outside the node group and it won't affect any other materials. Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to go into/out of the group.

[image: emission strength slot]

I used the *[Node Arrange](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_arrange.html)* add-on that comes with Blender to properly align the nodes, and then created the new input (*"Emission Strength "*) by dragging the *Strength* input into the empty *Group Input* slot. Then I renamed it in the side panel and moved the new slot below the *EmissionColor* slot.

Now you can control the emission strength in the material. Have fun with glow in the dark!

[image: controlling the emission strength for bloom]